# Emergency Escape for page by button click or ESC button

Tags: wordpress, redirect

I am trying to use the code here to make an emergency escape:
https://css-tricks.com/website-escape/

It is being used on a Wordpress site here: http://b67.3d8.myftpupload.com/ but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried adjusting the location of the script to no avail. Can anyone see what is going on?

HTML:

```
<button id="get-away">Go <a href="#" title="Click here press ESC to get away quickly">?</a></button>
```

JS (in `<head>` section):

```
      <script>
            function getAway() {
              // Get away right now
              window.open("http://weather.com", "_newtab");
              // Replace current site with another benign site
              window.location.replace('http://google.com');
            }

            $(function() {

              $("#get-away").on("click", function(e) {
                getAway();
              });

              $("#get-away a").on("click", function(e) {
                // allow the link to work
                e.stopPropagation();
              });

              $(document).keyup(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 27) { // escape key
                  getAway();
                }
              });

            });
        </script>
```

Comment: you `$` (jQuery) is not defined.

Comment: meaning, your jquery is included later, than when you use it - put it in a document ready as well

Comment: I am not sure I understand. I have tried various things like moving the code after the jQuery is loaded in the header. I tried adding jQuery in front of  the function () instead of the $. I am not super familiar with jQuery so any help would be appreciated.